# The elements of $\frac{\mathbb{Z_n}[x]}{\langle ax+b \rangle}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

What does  elements of

> $$\displaystyle\frac{\mathbb{Z_n[x]}}{\langle ax+b \rangle }$$ lookes like

Every time i try to solve this kind of question i got stuck here .As we know that elements of $\mathbb{Z_n[x]}$ lookes like

> $$a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+....+a_mx^m$$where $a_0,a_1,a_2..a_m \in $ $\mathbb{Z_n}[x]$ and the elements of above ring looks like $$a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+....+a_mx^m+ \langle ax+b \rangle $$, but what is next .Please help

Thankyou

Comment: You are using the letter $n$ for two distinct purposes. That is not a good idea.

Comment: n is an integer.

Comment: Is that remark supposed to change the fact that you are using the letter $n$ for two distinct purposes?

Comment: please check it ,is it rigth?

Comment: Yes, except that $a^m$ should be $a_m$.

Comment: To simplify further you need to know the values of $\,a,b,n,\,$ e.g. if $a,n\,$ are coprime then $a$ is invertible so the ideal $= (x+b/a)$ so the quotient $\cong \Bbb Z_n.\,$

Comment: why ideal is $(x+b/a)$ can you please elaborate.

Comment: I scaled the ideal generator $\,ax+b\,$ by the unit (invertible) $\,a^{-1}.\,$ which doesn't change the ideal (easy to prove)

Comment: Okk got this,but last one how you said it is isomorphic yo $\mathbb{Z_n}$

Comment: $R[x]/(x-r)\cong R\,$ by the First Isomorphism Theorem, or directly, e.g. [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/115685/242)